# Python Compare Two Lists of Objects and Append to One List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare two lists of objects to see if a persons name matches in both lists.

```
list1 = ('Name', 'Kilometers Driven')
list1 example = ('John Doe', 500),('Jane Doe', 200)

list2 = ('Id','Name','Kilometers Walked','Total Events')
list2 example = (2,'Joe Doe',20,2),(3,'Frank Kelly',32,4)
```

If the person is present in both lists I want to take the Kilometers Driven and add it to the second list for that person.

Thanks for the help

Comment: so how should the desired result look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think dicts would suit your solution better, as you can access them via their keys (e.g. dict['km_driven']) which is less confusing than integer indices in a list.

This code works using lists:

```
# list1 = ('Name', 'Kilometers Driven')
list1 = [('Joe Doe', 500),('Jane Doe', 200)]

# list2 = ('Id','Name','Kilometers Walked','Total Events', optional='Kilometers Driven')
list2 = [(2,'Joe Doe',20,2),(3,'Frank Kelly',32,4)]

# Iterate through items of list1
for item1 in list1:
    # Iterate through items of list2
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        # Match 'Name' field in list1 to 'Name' field in list2
        if item1[0] == list2[i][1]:
            # Add 'Kilometers Driven' to that list2 item
            list2[i] = list2[i] + (item1[1], )

print(list2[0])
```

**Output:**

```
(2, 'Joe Doe', 20, 2, 500)
```

Comment: Hi rdimaio, thanks for the answer. When I print list2 after running through the code above it doesn't have the extra value added for Joe Doe

Comment: @seanie_oc Hey, did you change the name in list1? I had to change it from John Doe to Joe Doe, otherwise there would have been no matching names

Comment: I did that thanks and if I put that item after it runs "item2 = item2 + (item1[1], )" it shows the desired results but when I put list2 after all the loops have completed it just shows the original list

Comment: @seanie_oc You are right. I fixed the code and posted the new version in the original comment.

Answer (score 1):

Given data lists:
(list1 and list 2 are a list of tuples.)

`list1 = [ ('John Doe', 500), ('Jane Doe', 200) ]`

`list2 = [ (2,'John Doe',20,2), (3,'Frank Kelly',32,4) ]`

```
for i in list1:
  name,km=i #unpacking tuple into name and km driven
  for index,j in enumerate(list2): #iterate list2 with index
   if name in j: # if name exists in element j of list2
     two[index]=two[idx]+(km,) #add km driven to element j
```

The value of list2 after the for loop:

`[(2, 'John Doe', 20, 2, 500), (3, 'Frank Kelly', 32, 4)]`

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries would make your task a lot more easier.
Here is an example.

```
dict1 = {'John Doe': 500, 'Jane Doe': 200}
dict2 = {'Joe Doe': [20, 2],'John Doe': [30, 3]}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if k in dict2.keys():
        dict2[k][0]+=v
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used namedtuple of python.

Sample Code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Type_1 = namedtuple('Type_1', 'Name Kilometers_Driven')
list_1 = [Type_1('John Doe', 500), Type_1('Jane Doe', 500)]


Type_2 = namedtuple('Type_2', 'Id Name Kilometers_Walked Total_Events')
list_2 = [Type_2(2, 'Joe Doe', 20, 2),
          Type_2(3, 'Frank Kelly', 32, 4),
          Type_2(3, 'John Doe', 10, 3)]

for obj_1 in list_1:
   for idx, obj_2 in enumerate(list_2):
       if obj_1.Name == obj_2.Name:
           total = obj_2.Kilometers_Walked + obj_1.Kilometers_Driven
           list_2[idx] = obj_2._replace(Kilometers_Walked = total)

print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

[Type_1(Name='John Doe', Kilometers_Driven=500), Type_1(Name='Jane Doe', Kilometers_Driven=500)]

[Type_2(Id=2, Name='Joe Doe', Kilometers_Walked=20, Total_Events=2), Type_2(Id=3, Name='Frank Kelly', Kilometers_Walked=32, Total_Events=4), Type_2(Id=3, Name='John Doe', Kilometers_Walked=**510**, Total_Events=3)]

As you can see kilometer is getting updated correctly